# Days of the Week Switch Construct - Am I Doing This Right?

Tags: java, int, switch-statement

The assignment is to:
"Write a program that does the following: Declare a set of seven integer constants named MONDAY, TUESDAY, ... , SUNDAY. Set MONDAY to 1, TUESDAY to 2, and so forth. Then, create an integer variable named day_of_week and initialize it with some integer value. If the value of day_of_week is 1, the program should display Today is Monday. If the value is 7, the program should display Today is Sunday, and so forth. If the value is not in the range 1-7, the program should display the message Invalid Data. Use a switch construct and the defined constants as part of the switch."

I was wondering if I was doing something wrong or if there is anything I should change since I am just starting out with Java and am trying to learn and get better.

Here is my code:

```
public class DaysOfWeek {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int MONDAY = 1;
        int TUESDAY = 2;
        int WEDNESDAY = 3;
        int THURSDAY = 4;
        int FRIDAY = 5;
        int SATURDAY = 6;
        int SUNDAY = 7;

        int day_of_week = 1;

        switch(day_of_week)

        {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Today is Monday");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Today is Tuesday");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Today is Wednesday");
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Today is Thursday");
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Today is Friday");
                break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("Today is Saturday");
                break;

            case 7:
                System.out.println("Today is Sunday");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Data");
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks fine. do you have some errors?

Comment: The errors are: it doesn't match the spec. That neither a compile-time nor run-time problem so you won't pick it up by compiling or running the code. What we need in our tool chain is an intelligent specification checker :-)

Comment: I would suggest you look at the constants in `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors I just want to make sure it's all good so I don't get marked off

Answer (score 4):

That's a good attempt so kudos for trying but, if the specs state:

> Use a switch construct ***and the defined constants*** as part of the switch.

then you should be using `MONDAY` rather than `1` in your `switch` statement (ditto for the other days):

```
case MONDAY:
    blah_blah_blah();
```

Additionally, those aren't actually *constants* so you want to make them `final` (and move them outside of `main` but still inside the class) to ensure they are:

```
static final int MONDAY = 1;
```

And, for both consistency and readability, you probably want to initialise it with the symbolic value as well:

```
int day_of_week = MONDAY;
```

Comment: I changed them all and now I'm getting an error that says "case expressions must be constant expressions" for every day of the week that I changed in the switch statement. Any idea how I can fix it? (Thanks for the help btw).

Comment: @cpitt6477: see the update, a commenter (rightly) called out the issue but has deleted the comment now that I've modified the answer to fix it).

Comment: wait I didn't see the second part I'm going to try that